# Create a Sprite from image array

Tags: sprite, easeljs, todataurl

An Image array created from series of calls to toDataUrl() metod of the canvas.
Now I need to create a SpriteSheet out of it.

How do I do that?

```
var imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
var image = new Image();
image.src = imgUrl;
arr.push(image);
```

I've read EaselJS docs on SpriteSheet [here](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html). But there is no such methods or examples how to create it in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `SpriteSheetBuilder`:
http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheetBuilder.html

There are also some examples here:
https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/examples

Keep in mind that you have to include SpriteSheetBuilder separately as it is not part of the "core"-library (https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/593).

Edit:
Example of how to use the normal SpriteSheet with image-instances...  Just pass them to the data-object and calculate your frames before.

```
var data = {
    images: arr, //pass your array with images
    frames: (...)
};
var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't need the SpriteSheetBuilder. I'm just not sure how to build a SpriteSheet from an array of Image instances in runtime.

Comment: Ah sorry, then I misunderstood your question. ;-) You can just pass you image instances as you would do with a normal "image": Check the example (+ my edit) on http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html